# Can't successfully run list comprehension on list of lists in python

Tags: python, exception, list-comprehension

I am trying to add an 'https:' prefix to links in a list if they do not have one to begin with. However, when I run this, nothing happens to the existing lists. Can anyone tell me why?

```
pdf = ['//www.website.com/pdf_file.pdf', '//www.website2.com/pdf_file.pdf']
con = []
redir = ['//www.redirectlink.com/download']
no_anchor_pdf = []

lol = [pdf, con, redir, no_anchor_pdf]


for l in lol:
    try:
        if l[0][0:6] != 'https:' and l[0][0:6] != 'http:/':
            l =  ['https:' + item for item in l]
            print('added prefix')
        else:
            pass
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: Because you never change the existing lists and only create some new lists which are not referenced anywhere at the end.

Comment: You should also remove the `except: pass` because all it does is hiding the error messages from you that are telling you what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using regex it makes easier the solution

```py
pdf = ['//www.website.com/pdf_file.pdf', '//www.website2.com/pdf_file.pdf']
con = ['https://stackoverflow.com/']
redir = ['//www.redirectlink.com/download']
no_anchor_pdf = []

lol = [*pdf, *con, *redir, *no_anchor_pdf]

import re
for i in range(len(lol)):
    if re.match('^https',lol[i]):
        continue
    else:
        res=f'https:{lol[i]}'
        lol[i]=res
print(lol)
#['https://www.website.com/pdf_file.pdf', 'https://www.website2.com/pdf_file.pdf', 'https://stackoverflow.com/', 'https://www.redirectlink.com/download']
```